# Async for loop on AsyncGenerator

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Having an asynchronous generator I would expect to be able to iterate through it asynchronously. However, I am missing something or messing something up or both as I end up with a regular synchronous for loop in the end:

```
import asyncio


async def time_consuming(t):
    print(f"Going to sleep for {t} seconds")
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    print(f"Slept {t} seconds")
    return t


async def generator():
    for i in range(4, 0, -1):
        yield await time_consuming(i)


async def consumer():
    async for t in generator():
        print(f"Doing something with {t}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(consumer())
    loop.close()
```

This will take about 12 seconds to run and return this:

```
Going to sleep for 4 seconds
Slept 4 seconds
Doing something with 4
Going to sleep for 3 seconds
Slept 3 seconds
Doing something with 3
Going to sleep for 2 seconds
Slept 2 seconds
Doing something with 2
Going to sleep for 1 seconds
Slept 1 seconds
Doing something with 1
```

Though I expected it to take about 4 seconds to run and return something like this:

```
Going to sleep for 4 seconds
Going to sleep for 3 seconds
Going to sleep for 2 seconds
Going to sleep for 1 seconds
Slept 4 seconds
Doing something with 4
Slept 3 seconds
Doing something with 3
Slept 2 seconds
Doing something with 2
Slept 1 seconds
Doing something with 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An asynchronous generator does not mean that you execute iteration concurrently! All that you gain is more places for the coroutine to yield to other tasks. The iteration steps still *run in series*.

Put differently: an asynchronous iterator is useful for an iterator that needs to use I/O to obtain each iteration step. Think looping over the results of a web socket, or lines in a file. If each `next()` step over the iterator requires waiting for a slow I/O source to provide data, that's a good point to yield control to something else that has been set to run concurrently.

If you expected each individual step of your generator to be run concurrently, then you still would have to schedule additional tasks, *explicitly*, with the event loop.

You can then return from the generator when all those extra tasks have completed. If you scheduled your 4 `time_consuming()` coroutines as tasks, use [`asyncio.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) to wait for one or all of the tasks to complete, and yield results from tasks that are done, then yes, after your `for i in range(...):` loop is complete, your process would only take 4 seconds in total:

```
async def generator():
    pending = []
    for i in range(4, 0, -1):
        pending.append(asyncio.create_task(time_consuming(i)))

    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for task in done:
            yield task.result()
```

at which point the output becomes

```
Going to sleep for 4 seconds
Going to sleep for 3 seconds
Going to sleep for 2 seconds
Going to sleep for 1 seconds
Slept 1 seconds
Doing something with 1
Slept 2 seconds
Doing something with 2
Slept 3 seconds
Doing something with 3
Slept 4 seconds
Doing something with 4
```

Note that this is the *reverse* order from your expected output, because this takes task results *as they complete* rather than wait for the first task to be created to complete. Usually this is what you want, really. Why wait for 4 seconds when you already have a result ready after 1?

You can have your variant too, of a sort, but you'd just code that up differently. Then you can just use [`asyncio.gather()` on the 4 tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), which schedules a bunch of coroutines to run as concurrent tasks, and return their results as a list, after which you can yield those results:

```
async def generator():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(4, 0, -1):
        tasks.append(time_consuming(i))

    for res in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
        yield res
```

but now the output becomes

```
Going to sleep for 4 seconds
Going to sleep for 3 seconds
Going to sleep for 2 seconds
Going to sleep for 1 seconds
Slept 1 seconds
Slept 2 seconds
Slept 3 seconds
Slept 4 seconds
Doing something with 4
Doing something with 3
Doing something with 2
Doing something with 1
```

because we can't do anything further until the longest task, `time_consuming(4)`, has completed, yet the shorter-running tasks complete before that point and already output their `Slept ... seconds` message.

Comment: Got it. I was avoiding the explicit scheduling of tasks on the event loop since I don't know properly how to do it inside the running loop. Maybe I need to exit it and then schedule the tasks in a new loop. I'll do my research. And yes, the `time_consuming` function awaits some requests in my real code.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins: that's as simple as `asyncio.create_task()`.

Comment: Thank you **very much**! The order I expected was just a wrong guess. Your solution scheduling tasks and enqueueing 'em is perfect.

Comment: I've experimented with `asyncio.gather` but I didn't use it exactly because I had to wait for the gathering of all tasks before processing the results.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins: sorry, I had overcomplicated things with a queue. All you need here is to wait for the tasks to complete, so `done` has all the information we need.

Comment: @MartjinPieters I was just testing going without the queue, thanks!

Comment: *An asynchronous generator does not mean that you execute iteration consecutively!* - did you mean to write "concurrently"? The iterations *are* consecutive (one following the other).

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks, yes, absolutely. I’ll go get my brown paper bag now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters :D Note that there are a couple more places in the answer that use consecutively the same way.

Comment: @user4815162342: and after a few *consecutive* edits, and two independent re-reads by family members (executed concurrently), I am now confident that all the vocabulary errors by the weirdo with the brown bag over there have been corrected. You know, the weirdo over there in the mirror?

Comment: The last example doesn't work for me - in my Python 3.7 `yield from` inside an `async def` raises `SyntaxError: 'yield from' inside async function`

Comment: @user4815162342 I had and found the same error then forgot to update the sample here.